# Placing links in Bootstrap navbar to spread through all the navbar area

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I designed a navbar using bootstrap 4 all the links can move to the left 
and right using Ml and MR auto what i want is the links i created to be 
evenly distributed on the nav bar what can be done to achieve this thank you. my code below.

```
   <div class="container">
              <h1 class="text-muted"> Jumia Sale Page</h1>
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
                  <button class="navbar-toggler " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcollapse">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="collapse justify-content-center  navbar-collapse" 
         id="navbarcollapse">
                      <ul class ="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                          <li class="nav-item  active"><a href="#"class="nav- 
      link">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"class="nav-link">Downloads</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>

              </nav>

          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `justify-content-between w-100` on the `navbar-nav` to evenly distribute the nav items...

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-between w-100">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/zkgcXDSqTf

Comment: Thanks a bunch works perfectly. Kindly explain the use of w-100

Comment: It's `width:100%` to make the navbar-nav full width

Comment: Thank you very much